# Is it possible to modify method name of a method in a java class during runtime

Tags: java

I need to modify all the methods in a class(lets say in program1) by appending the prefix "remotable" infront of the method name. But this need to be done at runtime by another java program (lets say program2). Is this  possible? 
For example: the method in program 1

```
public void print() {  
    //implementation
}
```

should be modified as

```
public void remotableprint(){ 
    //same implementation no change
}
```

by the program 2.

If it is not possible to modify the method name is there any other way that could be used to mark a method to distinguish it from other methods during runtime?

Please if this is possible can anyone tell me how?

Comment: You want to rename methods at runtime? Write your own classloader.

Comment: This is called refactoring and any good IDE (like Eclipse) will offer that functionality.

Comment: Shouldn't be done at runtime.  IDE can do it while developing.

Comment: Look into something called "reflection".

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  If you want to modify the *pre-compiled* code then that's just a text file.  You can modify text files.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But unless you are more specific about what you are really trying to achieve here, it is not possible to suggest the best way(s) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

when you modified in JVN runtime，you can use "reflection",such as you method is private,but you use "reflection" that you can through setAccessible() to change this method modifiers but this change not to alter java file ! when you modified this java file,this java file is not allow in use,you can use class of "File" to change you local file!!